# Is action like sort list without catching return data into local list allowed in Java?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I know of the way Java passes object references, but this piece of code really confused me.

Intro: On app start, a service fetches JSON data, parses it and maps it into data models. Then we need to load a specific list into `ListView`, but we also need to sort and reverse it before. The line of code looks like this

```
Collections.sort(Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys());
Collections.reverse(Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys());
//...
//pass HistoryKey object to some other method after a few lines
```

where the called method `getHistoryKeys()` simply returns list object filled by the service on app start.

Is this really allowed in Java?

I would code it like this and it seems that I am wrong.

```
ArrayList<Key> keysList = Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys()
Collections.sort(keysList);
Collections.reverse(keysList);
//...
//pass keysList object to another method after a few lines
```

Am I the only one who finds my code more readable and easier to understand to someone who will maintain the project after me?

Comment: The original is more readable, but yours is safer and less likely to have bugs.  I'd use your approach personally.  The original is basically a global variable that can be manipulated at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is more readable: `keysList` is short, so reading it repeatedly is a lot easier than reading `Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys()` twice.
In fact, "Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys()" is so long,
it forces me to read carefully to verify that it's really the same thing twice, and there is no difference between the two.

But instead of using `ArrayList` as the type, you should use the interface type:

```
List<Key> keysList = Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys();
Collections.sort(keysList);
Collections.reverse(keysList);
```

And instead of sort + reverse, you should do it in one step:

```
Collections.sort(Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys(), Collections.reverseOrder());
```

... in which case, now it's no longer better to use a separate `keysList` variable, since `Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys()` only appears once, it's fine like that.

Comment: I personally use `List<T>` always, but this method returns `ArrayList<T>` so (again!) I did not analyse the code at the time I was writing the question.

Comment: Even if the method returns `ArrayList<T>`, you can (and usually should) assign it to a variable declared as `List<T>`

Comment: Thanks Jason. I am actually doing it each time but I had no idea that I am doing such a good thing with it :).

Answer (score 2):

If `Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys()` always returns a reference to the same underlying object, this code would work. It's a matter of style, mostly, but I tend to agree this isn't the best practice. Nothing it the API suggests that it indeed always returns the same object, which makes this code unclear, at least at first glance.

Regardless, sorting a list and then reversing its order is definitely a bad piece of coding, when you could just as easily have sorted it in reverse order to begin with:

```
Collections.sort
    (Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys(), Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Or, to follow your suggestion:

```
List<Key> keysList = Datastorage.getInstance().getHistoryKeys()
Collections.sort(keysList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: LOL Thanks for the last suggestion. I was actually trying to copy the code without analysing it. So upvote for that as well.

Comment: `[...] to copy the code without analysing it.` - Stackoverflow overflows of people doing this. :)